# In eclipse IDE, I'm unable to access org.apache.logging.log4j package. I have even imported both "log4j-core-2.18.0.jar" and "log4j-api-2.18.0.jar"

Tags: java, log4j

```
package Alpha;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `requires org.apache.logging.log4j;` to your `module-info.java` file like so:

```
module LoggerTest {
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
}
```